# JUnit dependency not available in Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit-jupiter

I have already rebuilt the Maven repository, but my Maven still does not see JUnit:

[image: I have already rebuilt the Maven repository, but my Maven still does not see JUnit]

I use Eclipse IDE,
Tried reinstalling the library also manually installed maven,
Replaced part of the code in pom, does anyone know how to solve the problem

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What command are you running? Have you tried outside Eclipse?

Comment: run as maven build

Answer (score 2):

The log says `Compiling 2 source files to C:\workspace\Reverse2\target\classes` instead of ...`target\test-classes` which indicates that `src/test` is handled as main code, not as test code. In main code, dependencies with the scope `test` are not available, hence the compile error.

In Maven **test code** is by default in **`src/test/java`**, not in `src/test`.

Comment: you were right the problem was in the name of the source folder and the package was not involved thank you)